# Cross compiling with clang on cmake, linker does not support armelf_linux_eabi

Tags: c++, c, cmake, compilation

Here's my cmake toolchain file to cross compile for arm linux:

```
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME Linux)
set(CMAKE_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR arm)

set(CLANG_TARGET_TRIPLE arm-linux-gnueabihf)
set(GCC_ARM_TOOLCHAIN_PREFIX ${CLANG_CLANG_TARGET_TRIPLE})
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER clang)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER_TARGET ${CLANG_TARGET_TRIPLE})
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER clang++)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_TARGET ${CLANG_TARGET_TRIPLE})
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER clang)
set(CMAKE_ASM_COMPILER_TARGET ${CLANG_TARGET_TRIPLE})
```

Here's the problem when I execute cmake with it:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake:52 (message):
  The C compiler

    "/usr/bin/clang"

  is not able to compile a simple test program.

  It fails with the following output:

    Change Dir: /home/lz/orwell/gtk/build/armlinux/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

    Run Build Command:"/usr/bin/make" "cmTC_8132a/fast"
    /usr/bin/make -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_8132a.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_8132a.dir/build
    make[1]: Entering directory '/home/lz/orwell/gtk/build/armlinux/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Building C object CMakeFiles/cmTC_8132a.dir/testCCompiler.c.o
    /usr/bin/clang --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf    -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_8132a.dir/testCCompiler.c.o   -c /home/lz/orwell/gtk/build/armlinux/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCCompiler.c
    Linking C executable cmTC_8132a
    /usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_8132a.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
    /usr/bin/clang --target=arm-linux-gnueabihf      -rdynamic CMakeFiles/cmTC_8132a.dir/testCCompiler.c.o  -o cmTC_8132a 
    /usr/bin/ld: unrecognised emulation mode: armelf_linux_eabi
    Supported emulations: elf_x86_64 elf32_x86_64 elf_i386 elf_iamcu i386linux elf_l1om elf_k1om i386pep i386pe
    clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    CMakeFiles/cmTC_8132a.dir/build.make:97: recipe for target 'cmTC_8132a' failed
    make[1]: *** [cmTC_8132a] Error 1
    make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/lz/orwell/gtk/build/armlinux/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
    Makefile:126: recipe for target 'cmTC_8132a/fast' failed
    make: *** [cmTC_8132a/fast] Error 2
```

It looks like it's trying to use `/bin/ld` instead of clang's linker (is there one?). I know that there exists [CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_EXTERNAL_TOOLCHAIN](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.6/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER_EXTERNAL_TOOLCHAIN.html#variable:CMAKE_%3CLANG%3E_COMPILER_EXTERNAL_TOOLCHAIN) but I don't know the path to include and preferably I didn't want to include any paths, I'd like to make it work without path specification.

So, how to specify a compatible linker?

Comment: `unrecognised emulation mode: armelf_linux_eabi`
    `Supported emulations: elf_x86_64 elf32_x86_64 elf_i386 elf_iamcu i386linux elf_l1om elf_k1om i386pep i386pe`

Comment: @KamilCuk yes, because `/bin/ld` is being used. Shouldn't I use another linker (perhaphs llvm) which supports `armelf_linux_eabi`?

Comment: Is there a clang linker? `set(CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE ...)`

Comment: @KamilCuk I don't know. Do you mean llvm?

Comment: @KamilCuk I used `set(CMAKE_C_LINK_EXECUTABLE /usr/bin/llvm-link-8)` and I got: `/usr/bin/llvm-link-8
    llvm-link-8: Not enough positional command line arguments specified!
`

Comment: @LucasZanella try specifying `/usr/bin/lld`

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot `/usr/bin/lld
    Error running link command: No such file or directory`

Comment: @LucasZanella you have to install the clang linker then.